# What's the difference between response.setContentType and response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,contentType)

Tags: servlets, content-type

What's the difference between `response.setContentType` and `response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,contentType)`? If i set both,which works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no differences.
You can use them in the same way,

although, the implementation is a bit different..

in `response.setContentType` you set a content type directly to a private field of `Response` object.

but in `response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, contentType)` you set the content type using `HttpHeader` ENUM `CONTENT_TYPE` and specified a specific one...

As I said, no differences.. :)

BTW,

best practice is to stick to one way.. regardless what kind of way you'll choose, stick to it :)